# How to provide a default value in constructor with generic classes in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm wondering why TS is complaining about initializing a default value matching generic constraint in constructor ? In this example, an ORM must be initialized with a locator instance that maps some strings to property constructor.

If I provide the fallback locator as argument all is fine but if I try to define it as default value in constructor, TS is complaining. Here's the details :

```js
class Locator<R extends Record<string, unknown>> {
    readonly registry;

    constructor(registry: R) {
        this.registry = {...registry};
    }

    get<K extends keyof R>(k: K): R[K] {
        if(!(k in this.registry)) {
            throw new Error();
        }

        return this.registry[k] as R[K];
    }
}

interface IPropertyLocator extends Locator<Record<string, typeof Property>> {}

abstract class Property {}
class Property1 extends Property{}
class Property2 extends Property{}

const defaultLocator = new Locator({
    'p1': Property1,
    'p2': Property2
});

class ORM<P extends IPropertyLocator> {
    propertyLocator: P;

    constructor({properties}: {properties: P}) {
        this.propertyLocator = properties;
    }
}

const o1 = new ORM({properties: defaultLocator});

o1.propertyLocator;

class ORMFailure<P extends IPropertyLocator> {
    propertyLocator: P;

    constructor({properties = defaultLocator}: {properties ?: P} = {}) {
        this.propertyLocator = properties;
    }
}

const o2 = new ORMFailure();

o2.propertyLocator;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyD2wwBd4CcA8AlaBTAHsrgHYAmMWuw6pGEyaAlsQOYA00ArsQNbHwB3YgD5h0AN4AoaDOhpcYUvGIgAnnNwtG9NKoDck6bOrEdnYKjQAKeVp2qAXNCwBKCUdmzkAC20A6W20GdQBeCT8IwPsAXwNPaMNPFlxkDABpPEIScmgeXFV4ADNnYSseJzSXJywAbTSAXXdPT0ZCqwBCMuhmaB9-KOCXNylm0d7vNEFoYlwBaABRNEnrFzixhI9m+WRONGJx-s0g3RqeRshnOvq1mQSN5iI0QrBgXGgASQAFSYAHXDRkKoEEhLJkiGQYMCUOhsFQaHQGMx2L1VH8itBvvA-gDVKIJBswAAjHQvZDQUCQGCY7GA-GSClQDG-f6AgCMYOyVOZOPECQZXKxLNUACYORCmYKeRsTPRoKRcM9OCBkFDQWEZnNVegrCNZAByH6svVOalC1lsTYG4XGiU0kWSaKrQz86AAeSwAFkMJ8xTkvtzAVq0GJdTIfgGgYhoWgTQZNjKGOZLDrw5LkIxcBBok5xKmaRmICbHU0xn0IH480Kg9AwpWAQWbtA7s7lLL4Oz1bM3Z6UwGC055YrlUHHXH2xWI0G4y73R6AGJgRggXa4b2+mD+tORkHoEObOuBqOWWOJYytxMWbW5vuZmtyhVgJUqo-obMSA8F6AAfiLd95w02TwywnLdq1rG8IEbZt6XPaB4FFTs5lnBclxXKwnUkeCQLtKcgA)

Both `ORM` and `ORMFailure` classes are expecting to have a `IPropertyLocator` object provided within constructor arguments.

When trying to use a default value if none is provided as within `ORMFailure` class constructor, TS is complaining :

```
Type 'Locator<{ p1: typeof Property1; p2: typeof Property2; }>' is not assignable to type 'P'.
  'Locator<{ p1: typeof Property1; p2: typeof Property2; }>' is assignable to the constraint of
  type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint
  'IPropertyLocator'.(2322)
```

I can't see why providing a fallback value in constructor is hurting TS in this case. If none is provided, I whould have think that TS should infer type from `defaultLocator`.

At short term, I can obviously solve it by defining the ORM's propertyLocator as `P | typeof defaultLocator` but it will then fails to properly statically detect which locator is currently used. It complains about a signature mismatch when using the `get` method of the locator which is built to provide guard about available keys in locator.

Thanks !

Comment: It fails because the *caller* of the constructor chooses the type argument, not the implementer. I can call `new ORMFailure<MyCustomLocator>()` and the compiler is obliged to comply, but it can't; it's going to use the default thing which isn't a `MyCustomLocator`. That's what the error is. If you don't think this is likely and you want to work around it you can do so [like this](//tsplay.dev/w8Y44N) with a type assertion and a generic argument default.   Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Damned. You got it. Thanks a lot. Can you also explain in your answer why default Locator have to be cast as any ? I've already tried to default P to typeof defaultLocator in generic declaration but it also raised an error without your cast to any. There's definitely some weird logic for my mind in typescript Xo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error is pointing out a genuine (if unlikely to occur) type safety hazard with your `ORMFailure` constructor.  Type arguments of [generic classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes) are specified by the *caller* of the constructor, not the *implementer*.  Yes, these are often inferred by the compiler, but they are inferred on behalf of the caller.  And if the caller wants, they may *manually* specify the type argument instead of relying on inference.  So you could have something like this:

```
type MyCustomLocator = Locator<{ z: typeof Property2 }>;
const myOrm = new ORMFailure<MyCustomLocator>(); // okay
```

Here the caller specified `P` as `MyCustomLocator`, so `myOrm` is supposedly an instance of `ORMFailure<MyCustomLocator>`. The compiler can't complain about this;  it's the way generics work.  But of course your actual implementation of the constructor is going to use the default `defaultLocator` where a `MyCustomLocator` is expected, so even thought the following line compiles fine:

```
const oopsie = new (myOrm.propertyLocator.get("z"))(); // okay
```

You're going to get a runtime error inside of the `get()` method when `"z"` is not found in the registry.  Oopsie.

Let's look at that error again:

```
constructor({ properties = defaultLocator }: { properties?: P } = {}) { // error!
    // -----> ~~~~~~~~~~ 
    // 'Locator<{ p1: typeof Property1; p2: typeof Property2; }>' is assignable 
    //   to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a 
    //  different subtype of constraint 'IPropertyLocator'.
    this.propertyLocator = properties;
}
```

It's telling you that even though the type of the `defaultLocator` meets the `IPropertyLocator` [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `P`, this is not allowed because callers could specify a *different* `P` that doesn't match it.  Which is what I just did above, with its unpleasant consequences.

---

So what can we do?  Well, presumably it's quite unlikely that a caller will be confused or malicious enough to specify the type argument without passing in a value.  If we want to handle that situation there are ways to rewrite the `ORMFailure` constructor to do that, but the compiler still probably wouldn't be able to verify that they are safe.   I'm not going to pursue that approach in this answer.

Instead I'll assume that it's not going to happen in practice.  Then we can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that `defaultLocator` is in fact going to be assignable to `P` if no value is passed.  So something like `{ properties = defaultLocator as any }` will work.

Of course that still won't quite work, because there's nothing for the compiler to infer for `P` when a caller fails to pass in a `properties`.  Inference will just fail and `P` will fall back to the `IPropertyLocator` constraint.  If we want it to fall back to `typeof defaultLocator` instead, we'll want to set a [default generic type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).  So our class constructor will look like:

```
class ORMSuccess<P extends IPropertyLocator = typeof defaultLocator> {
    //                          default --> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    propertyLocator: P;

    constructor({ properties = defaultLocator as any }: { properties?: P } = {}) {
        //                         assert --> ^^^^^^
        this.propertyLocator = properties;
    }
}
```

---

Let's try it out.   When you don't specify the type argument or pass in a value it should now fall back to the default `P` you want:

```
const o3 = new ORMSuccess();
/* const o3: ORMSuccess<Locator<{
    p1: typeof Property1;
    p2: typeof Property2;
}>> */
const okay = new(o3.propertyLocator.get("p1"))(); // works
```

Looks good.  And when you don't specify the type argument but you *do* pass in a value, it should give you the `P` for that value:

```
const myCustomLocator: MyCustomLocator = new Locator({ z: Property2 });
const o4 = new ORMSuccess({ properties: myCustomLocator });
const stillOkay = new (o4.propertyLocator.get("z"))(); // also works
console.log(stillOkay.c.toFixed(2)) // "3.00"
```

Also looks good.  And if you *do* specify a type argument without passing in a value, *it will break* because our assumption about `defaultLocator` being assignable to type `P` will have been incorrect.  But we said we don't care about what happens to people who do such a thing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyD2wwBd4CcA8AlaBTAHsrgHYAmMWuw6pGEyaAlsQOYA00ArsQNbHwB3YgD5h0AN4AoaDOhpcYUvGIgAnnNwtG9NKoDck6bOrEdnYKjQAKeVp2qAXNCwBKCUdmzkAC20A6W20GdQBeCWg-SMD7aABfA09Yw08WXGQMAGk8QhJyaB5cVXgAM2dhKx4nDJcnLABtDIBdd09PRlKrAEIK6GZoH39o4Jc3KVbx-u80QWhiXAFoAFE0aesAIn58wug16ABqaABlBmYWCrcD3b6fXA07YLWXBImkj1b5ZE40YknBzSDdHUeM1IM4Go1njIkq9mEQ0MUwMBbgBJAAK0wADrg0MhVAgkJZskQyDB8Sh0NgqDQ6CdWBxcViStB0fAsTjVKJwq8wAAjHSI5DQUCQGAstm48JgaBhACMcUkwqgzMx2NxcoIxLyYtV6nE0B50ugACZ5YrRSr2SaNblzaydeFgIaAMzyhXKejQUi4BGcEDIMmEsJzBYB9BWMayADkGJlkac2vZMrYb2jRrjyrtlsksSehjN0AA8lgALIYVFEm3QNEW3GhtBiCMyDE1vGIcloeMGN4mMwWMN65uZ5CMXAwWJOAc1kcQeNxUZvTwDCB+Qfi1sE9CG1eq6eQ+WvHuC+ByoPzQsl8PQbc46dOL0+v11udd48rlt1rv5ovFgBiYEYIBfLgZYViSVYJrWbaWA2bzXpBG4dsyXaeIeaDmJYl5wdOhr3mAvr+lBm7juEWGjgA-LOsSGuIObhAA9HReArOgnQLrIDHQAAtNx3FiAAfgJglCdAbEyBxkZ1hgA4yk4DK4EyEGqDKehXkasmqIypSKUaKmxMIka9DAIqMCwxC8iAtyidAHEyKgky3Kh-7EEepRydAkaopGHA8pwgoeQZ1C+qQ+q3Mw9BgM5jAoLgwUCIwPjQFKVk2aQ7TFNiJCChAnA8m5TKObC7nVkO67tpGfhWUub4lU+YSkRAe7QoYbnFqoADCnD0PAAC2tVwIRmB6gAXupmkZmuJp6QYh7QN1qgFmg3WGsG56-v+gHyBgrUdV1vUDeUuaSMELTGO6R6shAI7LWeVhzQt3XVWudZ+KkyBWGsQ2PC4Vi5lRBLAN40BWLg84oe68AWX4IDwGcIPWYxmwFOoQ29D8Nx3ACqjZoYeZndA8AmqeCzfn+AFAT9L5Go9Oofnm4BKt+hzmEiUAgdaYHFU9A2GnJTK4fhdYwZ4NkTKLYv836XGcWIAB6cvywritK3LsHvgNnbJKdpgMOh-ZXlOo44d6eGPtzoIReoxGTkO04UcycTUbRjatCLYtu7IIqqlLsuK5VvjLnBpWBvrNujo12Nutr+MukTq1M8ALMQBTkh0QAVEKePwE6TiM8zo4QBgknOzGo3yVpLbKbBan9BpZfjTqOnZpyqd0ZHHrwDwYChLMN1Z9T7LPa970xl9FPw9AAjoDwEBtxDuBQzDVgd13fhgH4qA-ow+AxVYMojOPawyn4AAMaxt4Kc07age0IU422ddffUrXWl4jfXlrPuf+MACzXcTJbx0TphA2M5ZrtQfj1J8OZpp43oABEABZO7dxWkvb+-d4Lthemkd6n0Rhjw4mAEAEB4ATynjPHsc8F5nDgSABBSC-DAHXvATe29SBWCNPvDiawnQn1PkAA)